# Dragon Arum in the landscape

Tags: permaculture

Our property is becoming overrun by Dragon Arum, planted by a previous owner and exacerbated by some excavation work we’ve done. It’s very difficult to eradicate, so I’m wondering/hoping there’s some redeeming permaculture use for it in the garden.